# how to plot margin and edit in r

Tags: r

[image]

```
bins = seq(0,20,by=1)
hist(A,prob = TRUE,xlim= c(0,20),ylim= c(0,0.2),breaks=20,main="Frequency Distribution",xlab="Frequency",col="lightblue")
grid(nx = NA, ny = NULL, lty = 2, col = "gray", lwd = 1)
```

when i plot this, the margin lost even i zoom. but when i use par(mar=c(2,2)) the second one has margin

if then how can i edit my code? and edit the plot distance since i have 4 plot and title of plot will overlap x axis

Comment: If you have 4 plots, please show the code how you combine the figures. Did you eventually use `par(mfrow.....)` or `layout()` to subdivide plotting area?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the margin with `par(mar=c(bottom, left, top, right))`, see below. As your example did not contain A, I generated some random numbers. Note also that x is the random variable, not Frequency and that your `bins` and `grid`-lines are redundant,

```
par(mar=c(5,4,4,1))

A <- rnorm(1000, mean=10, sd=3)
hist(A,prob = TRUE,xlim= c(0,20),ylim= c(0,0.2),
 breaks=20, main="Frequency Distribution",xlab="Class", ylab="Density", col="lightblue")
```